# Cropping Image from Map Android Kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, google-maps, imageview

I have a Google Map in my Android Kotlin App. I want to do something as follows :

- The User should be able to cut out a rectangular portion from the map
- This rectangular portion should be send as an image to an API (Here the API accepts requests in the form of image in multipart data)
- The location of the cut-out area should also be send as a response to the API.

Any suggestions on how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try image cropper utill class...

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android) answer for take screenshots programatically, and use [this](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) library to crop it.

Comment: Ok...Thanks a lot. I will try it once.

Comment: @AlperenAcikgoz I tried taking the screenshot using Bitmap and Canvas. It is working for all other views except the map. For Maps I am getting a blank screenshot with only the word "Google" written at the bottom corner. Any suggestions on how to solve the issue?

Comment: @sceptre_rose  try implement snapshotReadyCallback it invokes when shapshot has been taken. [Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback) is the reference